# How can i include in a javascript more than one input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to do more than one javascript math function , i put two inputs , the first makes the own calculate and the result of the first , be part of the second calculate .

For example:

**HTML**

```
Total:
<input type="text" id="1" value=""  />
<p id="5"></p>
AMPI:
<input type="text" id="2" value="" />
<p id="4" ></p>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#1").keyup(function () {
 var value = $(this).val();
 var x=value*value;
 $("#3").text(x);
}).keyup();

$("#2").keyup(function () {
 var value = $(this).val();
 var y=value/ (**here i want the output <p id="3"></p>**) ;
 $("#4").text(y);
}).keyup();
```

Comment: I assume you want `$('#3').text()`. But I'm not sure. Read about the `.text` method: http://api.jquery.com/text/. Please reformulate your question so that is easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I thought this was going to be an awesome question about currying and lambdas. Sorely disappointed.

Comment: This question is poorly presented. Even after @Luiggi Mendoza edits!

Comment: i'm guessing `id="5"` should be `id="3"` and that in `#2`'s `keyup` you're wanting to divide `#2` by `#3` and put it in `#4`?

Comment: @cube I just edited the tags, not the question content. If you dislike, you can submit your own edit.

Comment: JavaScript or Jquery???

Comment: @Jorge, what are you asking?

Comment: To me it's not clear if he want's how can use one selector to handle the same event handler in Jquery or pure JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stating the obvious, you need to replace `(**here i want the output <p id="3"></p>**)` with `$("#3").text();`.

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/sjSaH/)**.

**UPDATE**:
In order to limit the number of fractional digits, you can use function `toFixed`. E.g.:

```
var x = 123.456789
$("#3").text(x.toFixed(3));   // <-- Displays: 123.457
```

Comment: can you please help me to include it in html ? when i try , it doesent show any result

Comment: Have you seen my demo ? I don't know how I can help you more than that. Maybe something is wrong with you HTML (a typo maybe). Have you corrected `id="5"` to `id="3"` ?

Comment: no the problem is that when i make my html file , it doesent work , i dont know maybe a problem with javascript include . can you please do it http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_whereto_head
like this

Comment: I pasted the whole HTML/CSS/JS code **[here](http://ideone.com/i28ddM)**. I hope that helps. Please, also, consider marking this answer as "accepted", if it helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: thank you very much , please how can i limit decimal in the result : for example 2.4923234 -> 2.492 ??

Comment: I updated my answer and the working demo. Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it helped you solve your problem (it's the green tick on the left :)).